# Select both records from duplicates based on if a value exists in group

Tags: sql, t-sql, group-by, duplicates

I have a table where there are duplicates in one column. I need to keep one of the duplicate records and delete the other. But before I delete one, I will have to point all other dependent table records that are tied to the one to delete, to the one I am going to keep. Also, if possible I would like to check a condition to choose the one to keep and delete, and if that condition does not meet then keep the `MIN()` and delete the `MAX()`.

For example I have this table called **workers**

[image]

I would like to group by the **workerID** column and then check if any 2 records within the group has a `isActive = 'No'`. If it does, grab that record's worker and mark it as **ToKeep**. If the **isActive** is Yes for both the records in the group, then make the `MIN(worker)` as ToKeep and `MAX(worker)` as ToDelete.

So, the result based on this example would be like this

[image]

Is it possible to write a query to do that? I tried writing the two queries below, but I got the wrong result both the times. Only the 10003 was showing up for both the results.

```
Select max(woWorker.pk) as  ToKeep, min(woWorker.Pk) as ToDelete
from woWorker 
group by woWorker.fkosCompanyWorker, woWorker.isActive
having (case when isActive = 'No' then 1 else 0 end) = 1


Select ToDelete = case when t.ToDelete is not null then t.ToDelete
                      else workers.worker end
from 
(Select Workers.worker as ToDelete, workerID
from Workers 
group by Workers.workerID, Workers.isActive, Workers.worker
having (case when isActive = 'No' then 1 else 0 end) = 1) t
join workers on t.workerID = workers.workerID
group by workers.workerID, t.ToDelete, workers.worker
```

Comment: Please read [this](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question. DDL and usable data is better than pictures of grids. Can there be more than one "duplicate" in a group?

Comment: No, I was only told there would be one duplicate per group.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use pivoting logic here, e.g.

```
SELECT
    workerID,
    CASE WHEN MIN(isActive) <> MAX(isActive)
         THEN MAX(CASE WHEN isActive = 'Yes' THEN worker END)
         ELSE MIN(worker) END AS ToKeep,
    CASE WHEN MIN(isActive) <> MAX(isActive)
         THEN MAX(CASE WHEN isActive = 'No' THEN worker END)
         ELSE MAX(worker) END AS ToDelete
FROM Workers
GROUP BY
    workerID;
```

[image: screen capture]

### Demo

However, if all you want to do is just view the records which are to be retained, then `ROW_NUMBER` provides one simple way to do that:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY workerID ORDER BY isActive DESC, worker) rn
    FROM Workers
)

SELECT worker, workerID, isActive
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1;
```

### Demo